# How to mock an object which hold others attributes(user defined pojo)?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito

I have a DataBinder class, which takes ModelObject in a constructor.
This model class has 3 attributes, they are user-defined classes, which holds data.
After mocking the user-defined classes, I am setting them to ModelObject.
Now, when I am passing ModelObject to DataBinder class, I am getting mocked objects as Null always.

Sample Code:

```
class ClassA {
    val attribute1 : String
    val attribute2 : String
}

class ClassB {
    val attribute1 : String
    val attribute2 : String
} 

class ClassC {
    val attribute1 : String
    val attribute2 : String
}

object ModelClass {
    val classA: ClassA
    val classB: ClassB
    val classC: ClassC
}
```

After mocking ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, I have used `when()` and `then()` functions.
Then passed Model Class to ViewBinder class. There I am getting all attributes as “Null”.

Comment: can you paste some example code here (especially the classes)

Comment: updated question description.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you mock the classes?

Comment: Is the model class also a mock in your test??